# How to trim this table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a sql noob and not sure how to explain this. So here is what I'm trying to achieve:

Original table

```
id   node_id    tag_id
-------------------------
1       10        3
2       10        4
3       10        1
4       11        7
5       11        8
```

Trimmed table:

```
id   node_id    tag_id
-------------------------
1       10        3
4       11        7
```

It should be simple but I really left clueless, so appreciate your help.

Comment: Explain in English what the rules are for which tag_id you want from each group of node_id.

Comment: @AndyLester for any given node_id, I want to remove all rows containing any occurrence of tag_id expect the first one. (so basically each node should have only one tag, the first one)

Comment: How do you define "the first one"?  The lowest numeric value?

Comment: @AndyLester no, the one that happen to have the least id.

Comment: What does "the least id" mean if not "lowest numeric value"?

Comment: @AndyLester, sorry,I mean I want to keep the one that has lowest `id` number (higher on the table), and remove the rest, as per example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you want to do, but the following produces the output you specify:

```
select min(id), node_id, min(tag_id)
from table t
group by node_id;
```

EDIT:

If you want to delete rows, then use `join`:

```
delete o
    from original_table ot left join
         (select min(id) as id
          from original_table
          group by node_id
         ) tokeep
         on ot.id = tokeep.id
    where tokeep.id is null;
```

This uses a `left join` to match to the minimum id for each `node_id`.  These are kept -- only non-matches are deleted.

Comment: Well I want to trim the original table in-place and delete unwanted rows.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do that would be to create a scratch table with the results of the `select` above, truncate the original table, and then insert the scratch table's rows back into the original.  You're only doing this once, right?